# Kernel gets busy when using nltk.download

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I am using jupyter notebook to practice this problem on kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words.

When I use the following code

import nltk 
nltk.download()  # Download text data sets, including stop words

Kernel goes in the busy state and then I am unable to execute any cells further.

Comment: Do you have python-tkinter installed on your system. `nltk.download()` opens up a tkinter window where you select the packages that you need to download. Once they are downloaded, close the window and jupyter will take you to the next cell. try running the same thing in the interactive shell as opposed to jupyter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `nltk.download()`, it launches an interactive GUI window that you can use to download resources. But very often this window is hidden behind other windows on your screen. Look for it, download anything you need and then **close the downloader window** in order for your script to return control to the notebook kernel.

To avoid hanging when your code gets to a download command, you could use a non-interactive download command instead. E.g., `nltk.download("brown")` for the Brown corpus, or `nltk.download("book")` to get all resources needed when reading through the nltk book. These carry out the download (even if you already have the requested resource) without opening a GUI window. For this you'll need to know, or guess, the internal name of the resource you want.